# CallKit - "Touch to return to call" not removing

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I am using CallKit in my project. "Touch to return to call" is still showing even when after the call is rejected by user those who called by us.

[image]

```
let provider = CXProvider(...) // this object declared globally
provider.reportCall(with: UUID(), endedAt: Date(), reason: CXCallEndedReason.declinedElsewhere)
```

I am using above code avoid this. But didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To end the call, use cxendcallaction and add the cxtransaction objects.
Make sure you are using the correct uuid.

```
CXEndCallAction *action = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:callUUID];
[self.callController requestTransaction:[CXTransaction transactionWithActions:@[action]] completion:completion];
```

Comment: callController is the object of what?

Comment: CXCallController object