# How to hide phone call screen during phone call in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, callkit, system-alert-window

I'm making a phone call app like Whatsapp or Messenger in Flutter. Does anybody know how to implement

- Hide phone screen to the top and show "tap to return to call" on iOS?
- float icon on other apps on Android?

I have found system_alert_window package and bubble_overlay package but they don't work on iOS.

[image: android chat head. Credit: Zeeshan rasool]
credit: Zeeshan rasool

[image: ios tap to return to call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594039/callkit-touch-to-return-to-call-not-removing]
[credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594039/callkit-touch-to-return-to-call-not-removing)

Comment: On iOS you need to implement CallKit functionality and you will get the default phone UI including the ability to minimise

Comment: as @Paulw11 mentioned you will have to dig deeper into both platform implementations and then use methodChannel to control the activities using dart.

Comment: Somebody in the world must have written this feature using platform specific channels in Flutter. Do you know any sample? I googled whole day but can't find.